# Location of email address book, inbox in horde cpanel backup

Tags: centos, ssh, email, horde

I have a large backup of an old web-server that I can only SSH into. I need to be able to locate the location of the email accounts, address books and any email that was caught on the server at the time of the backup. The server was running centOS, cpanel with horde/squirrel/roundcube mail clients.

I've had a cursory look through the file structure but rather approach it folder by folder I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction a little faster. So, where do I need to go looking for the email account information, my priority is accessing the address book and email stored in the account.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are looking for is probably called horde.sql and is located in /cpanel-name/mysql/horde.sql

Typing `locate horde.sql | more` should also do a search if the location is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Check /home/{cpanel-username}/mail. That should at least be your starting point.

- David